# How to make “FusionCharts("CompId").setJSONUrl(serviceUrl);” executed sequentially (synchronous) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, synchronization

I want to ask some stuff about FushionChart. It is about command setJSONUrl in FushionChart.
How to make it run sequentially (synchronous), so the other javascipt command after that will only run after it finishes rendering chart.
I have tested it in web console (using Chrome) with this command :

```
FusionCharts("KPI1_3G").setJSONUrl(serviceUrl);
console.log(1);
console.log(2);
```

Then the output in console like this :

```
1
2
undefined
```

From that output we know that console.log commmands **console.log(1);** and **console.log(2);**

are executed earlier than **FusionCharts("KPI1_3G").setJSONUrl(serviceUrl);**

So how to make it executed sequentially in order of Javascript command?

So many thanks for the answer